# Combo not displaying select item and showing as an item list

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox, datagrid

```
 public void DataGrid_Data()
    {
        // 2 second delay before loading DataGrid
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.80) };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();

            // Attemption to connect to SQL Server database and populate DataGrid with database tables. 
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [hb_Disputes].[DSP_ID], [hb_disputes].[ACCOUNT], [Users].[TX_EMPLOYEE], [hb_CsrNames].[NM_USER], [hb_disputes].[CUST_NAME],[hb_disputes].[PREM_ADDR], [hb_status].[Status], [hb_disputes].[OPENED], [hb_disputes].[DEADLINE], [hb_disputes].[DATERSLVD], [hb_rpttype].[ReportType], [hb_ratetype].[RateType], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DT_FIRSTREV], [hb_Disputes].[FR_TS_LATESTUPD], [hb_Disputes].[COMMENT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DSP_CLSF], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CUST_CNTCT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_WRK_REQ], [hb_Disputes].[FR_OPN_ERR], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_TP], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DTLS], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DT_WNTD], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_ISSD_BY], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CMMNT] FROM [hb_disputes]" +
                    " LEFT JOIN [Users] ON [hb_disputes].[ASSGNTO] = [Users].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_CsrNames] ON [hb_disputes].[WFMUSER] = [hb_CsrNames].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_status] ON [hb_disputes].[STATUS] = [hb_status].[STSID] LEFT JOIN [hb_rpttype] ON [hb_disputes].[RPTTYPE] = [hb_rpttype].[RPTID] LEFT JOIN [hb_ratetype] ON [hb_disputes].[REV_CLS] = [hb_ratetype].[RTID]", connection);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                connection.Close();

                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;

                // Focus in on line 1 of the data grid on UserControl load 
                // So it can be shown in the key information side column

                dtGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                dtGrid.Focus();
                dtGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection is not available at this time. Please contact your database administrator ");
            }
        };
    }


    private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if (gd != null)
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_analyst.Text = row_selected["TX_EMPLOYEE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Status.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_firstreview.Text = row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Latestupdate.Text = row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_reviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();



            // ComboBoxes

            windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRowView row in dtGrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add(row.Row["ReportType"].ToString());
            }

            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

The code shows my Datagrid being loaded by an SQL Server database and on a double click event a new Window opens and the Datagrid row information is populated in the textbox and comboboxes fields.

I am trying to display the already selected "Utility Report Type" however, I can only get it to show as a combobox item with windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add(row.Row["ReportType"].ToString());

I have some back end code that populates that combo box but on the Loaded event, which also pulls from a SQL Server database but I've disabled it for this example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the SelectedIndex property to display the item as selected.

The Items.Add() returns the index of the newly added item.

This means, (I assume that only one row can be selected from the grid), the following should suffice:

Change:

```
cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add("My Report Type");
```

To:

```
cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add("My Report Type");
```

Comment: I got it to display as a text (varchar) and my database is expecting a numeric. I have some behind code for the combo box in the window where it is located to populate the values. Is there any way I can use SelectedValuePath or DiplayMemeberPath to bind everything?